# Selectric search within results

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectric

I'm using [selectric](http://selectric.js.org) - plugin for replacing select in forms and I'm struggling with the add search option, sadly this plugin does not come with such a feature.

I got to the point where I can create an input over label and refresh options after typing something, but it does not work as I expect. I got to this point:

`jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/fcamjb57/

The issue is as you click the input, the whole select closes.

Comment: Why you don't use select2?

Comment: switch to select2 it's easier and more globally used than that you are using...