# How to Enable Word Search using Selectric.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectric

The selectric documentation says it has search functionality. https://selectric.js.org/

However, I have not found one example online of how to enable / configure it.

Comment: You're right, it does say it has search, but there's no options for it. Funnily enough in researching an answer I found a SO question which basically says ['don't bother, just use Select2'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53840430/519413), and I have to say I agree. Select2 is far better

Comment: Yeah, I might end up having to switch libraries. I wanted to avoid doing that since then I'd have to re-factor a lot of code because selectric is being used everywhere in our application.